# How to set input element value to some string which has double quotes?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code I am not able to set a value which has double quotes.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d"/>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
</body>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = function() {
        var d = document.getElementById("d");
        var value = 'some"val\'ue';
        var h = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"someid\" value=\"" + value + "\">"
        d.innerHTML = h;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Is there any way to do it?

**Note**: Due to some reasons I cant render the `input` element first and later set the value using `.value`. I have to do it using `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&quot;` is html way of saying `"`.

Comment: +1 And it's really important to remember that the text you put in an attribute's value is HTML text. (True even of the `href` attribute, where it's **hugely** common to fail to properly encode `&`.)

Comment: Thank You, before your answer somehow using `quot;` was not working. Now it works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, true. To put in in general way — attributes should be about as well escaped as any text you would want to see in html literally.